# calculating time complexity

Tags: time-complexity

i tried calculating time complexity for this code:[image]

the answer i got is n since the the space complexity is logn and i calculated the sum of geometric sequence with q=4 and n=logn. but apparently its sqrt(n) can someone explain why?

Comment: notice run time $T(n)=4T(n/16)+\Theta(1)$ , have you learned master theorem?

Comment: $n=\log n$ does not make sense.

Comment: @C.C. i missed that, thank you!!